# pyqt: Adding a custom column to QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I need to add an extra column to the QFileSystemModel. I've seen the answer at: [QT - adding own column to QFileSystemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962902/qt-adding-own-column-to-qfilesystemmodel)
Would someone tell me how I can properly define the subclass in pyqt4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can almost copy paste the C++ code. Here is the pyqt implementation:

```
class YourSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):

    def columnCount(self, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return super(YourSystemModel, self).columnCount()+1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.column() == self.columnCount() - 1:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QString("YourText")
            if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
                return QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter

        return super(YourSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
```